# Magento upgrade issue from 1.3.0.0 to 1.6.2.0

Tags: magento

I am running in to an issue and I am not sure how to fix it. I am very new to Magento and PHP so don’t know much about the errors and I usually google it to fix it but can’t seem to find anything for this issue.

I am getting the error below. After upgrading to 1.6.2.0, Magento was using a theme called “modern” but when I changed it to the theme I originally had, I get the error. I have also attached the file “list_sidebar.phtml” from the error seems to be originating.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
There has been an error processing your request

Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::myGetProductCollection(Array
(
    [0] => 18
)
)

Trace:
#0 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/design/frontend/default/lailides/template/catalog/product/list_sidebar.phtml(47): Varien_Object->__call('myGetProductCol...', Array)
#1 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/design/frontend/default/lailides/template/catalog/product/list_sidebar.phtml(47): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->myGetProductCollection('18')
#2 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/lailides/...')
#3 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#4 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#10 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/design/frontend/default/lailides/template/page/3columns.phtml(46): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#11 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/lailides/...')
#12 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#13 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(132): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#19 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#20 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#21 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#22 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /home/lailides/devmagento/store/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Answer (score 0):

A likely scenario is that in your 1.3.0.0 install, the core was directly modified to include a `myGetProductCollection` method, and that it got overwritten during the upgrade.

You should do a [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) between your original installation and [Magento 1.3.0.0](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download). That should tell you how your core deviates from a standard Magento installation.

Once you have identified these missing methods, you should implement them using [rewrites](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/174/changing_and_customizing_magento_code#blocks) instead, so that the next time you upgrade the same thing doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, if you had overwritten the core files, there must had some direct customization on the core files.

If you are not directly replacing core files and you are upgrading in different location then check app\code\local or app\code\community may be there are custom modules which overrides class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List and has custom function, then you can just move that module and it may start working again.

Good luck!